# How can I update a property inside a weaviate schema?

Tags: weaviate

How can I update an already defined property inside a weaviate schema?

I am expecting to know whether weaviate has already described any updates regarding the property updates inside a schema without changing the whole schema and how can it be implemented in weaviate schema.